# A Wonder Untold is Bright and Bold

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, lateral-thinking, acrostic

I have been sick lately and haven't written a riddle in probably a week or longer. I came up with a riddle this morning while adding more detail to the [acrostic tag wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/acrostic/info) (though the edit still needs to be reviewed). You won't be able to find the answer there, but it will help guide you to the answer if you need it.

> Wondering why, why you are here?
>   Open your mind, you have no fear.
>   Nothing by me, though never alone;
>   Doubled risk, when openly shown.
>   Excitingandscary, all just the same;
>   Rearing its glory, taught in a game.
>   IMITATION MIGRAINES, ATTEMPT to GRASP IT!
>   NEVER ENDING story, always a classic.
>   Go forth now, conquer this here; emotions will rise, show me your tears.

In order for an answer to be accepted, you must answer the following questions:

- What are the acrostics?
- What is the answer?
- How does this answer relate to the acrostics?

### **Notes**

The answer is:

- One word.
- In the puzzle.
- Relates to all **three** acrostics.

As a bonus, how does the answer relate to the title?

Comment: Is "excitingandscary" intentional?

Comment: I would assume so. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial guess is

> the Mind

The acrostics could be

> Wondering, Imagine (first letters of caps) and Brain (found if you take the 9th character of the 3rd through 7th rows and explains why Excitingandscary has no spaces)

The answer is

> in the puzzle (literally the word mind is in the puzzle), one word, relates to wondering, imagine and brain directly.

The clues
Wondering why, why you are here?

> Self awareness, philosophical wonderings

Open your mind, you have no fear.

> literally mentioning the mind

Nothing by me, though never alone;

> not physical, but always thinking or dreaming

Doubled risk, when openly shown.

> speak your mind and take the consequences

Excitingandscary, all just the same;

> all emotions come from the mind, perhaps

Rearing its glory, taught in a game.

> now your playing mind games with me

IMITATION MIGRAINES, ATTEMPT to GRASP IT!

> I'm getting a headache just thinking about this one

NEVER ENDING story, always a classic.

> Does the mind/soul persist after the body goes?

Go forth now, conquer this here; emotions will rise, show me your tears.

> again, the well of emotions springs from the mind?

ok, maybe not a great guess.  but maybe it will help someone

Comment: This Has to be it! That's why it was excitingandscary!

Comment: This is the correct answer; great catch on the third acrostic. I tried to make it obvious, but not too obvious. The only thing that I had a different view on was ***NEVER ENDING story, always a classic***; this is actually a reference to the book and movie [The Never Ending Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Neverending_Story) where the imagination of young Bastian just runs wild; it was partnered with the line prior, because it's hard to fathom what others can imagine.

Answer (score 3):

Well this’ll help someone out because I can’t find the third acrostic, but I do have

> WONDERING, the first letters of each line and IMAGINE, the first letters of the all-caps words. @SteveV got the third acrostic, BRAIN. Go upvote his answer!!! :D

This leads me to believe the answer is somewhat like

> Disney, which has an Imaginarium and also relates to a world of wonder.

Comment: The first three words start with "w" so maybe "www" somthing

Comment: You have the first two acrostics right on point. The answer is wrong though, good try!